# Baffled by solution to Vimscript recursion error

Tags: python, vim, org-mode

I want to use `gf` to open hyperlinked filenames in `.org` files (I use the vim plugin [vim-orgmode](https://github.com/jceb/vim-orgmode)):

[image]

I type `gf` and the file should open. To avoid having to move past the first two `[[`, I created the following script to do the job:

```
function! GFOrg()
python << EOF
import vim  
try:
    filename=vim.eval("@%")
    if filename.endswith(".org"):
        line = vim.current.line
        linkstart=line.find("[[")
        if linkstart != -1:
            row, start = vim.current.window.cursor
            vim.current.window.cursor = row, linkstart+2
    vim.command("normal gf")
except Exception as e:
    print("Error: {}".format(e))
EOF
endfunction
```

Now if I map it to override `gf`:

```
nnoremap gf :call GFOrg()<CR>
```

I get a recursion error:

[image]

But if I quit and reopen Vim (MacVim actually), and use `gfgf` as my mapping, I can just type `gf` (once) and it works fine:

```
nnoremap gfgf :call GFOrg()<CR>
```

Can anyone explain why I don't need to type `gf` twice to get mapped to the call, and why it stops the recursion error?

Comment: Unrelated aside: what happens if you have two links on a single line and you want to open the second one?

Comment: I'd update the script to cover that use case, so that it searches from the cursor: `linkstart=line.find("[[",vim.current.window.cursor[1]-1)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `:normal` to call `gf` which will call you mapping again which is causing the recursion. You should be using `:normal!` to avoid re-mapping.

That being said we can do better!

- Should a buffer-local mapping
- Only apply this mapping to buffer's the the `'filetype'` of `org`

Add the following to `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/org.vim`:

```
nnoremap <buffer> gf :call search('\[\[.', 'bce', line('.'))<cr>gf
```

Comment: Oh dang, I tried `normal ! gf` not realizing the space mattered. I'd like to give you two upvotes for those improved solutions, but can only give you one. I'll save the answered for anyone who can explain why `gfgf` is picked up by `gf`